# How to navigate to the details view from horizontal list on map view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I'm try to navigate through **NavigationView** and **NavigationLink(destination:** but it's not working for me.

```js
 ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        LazyHStack {
            
            ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { index in
                
                ZStack {
                    HListContentView(descriptionLineLimit: 3)
                        .background(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 20, height: 200)
                    
                        .onAppear {
                            print("map view: \(index)")
                        }
                        .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 10, x: 0.1, y: 0.1)
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView()) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                    
                    
                    .opacity(0)
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }
                
            }
            
        }
 //     }
}
```

[image: code screen shot]

[image: adding my app screen shot with data list and map]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved by using below 2 approaches:

**First:**

```
NavigationLink("Tap to show detail"){DetailsView()}
```

**Second:**

```
NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(), isActive: $isShowingDetailsView) {
                    EmptyView()
                    Button("Tap to show detail") {
                        isShowingDetailsView = true
                    }
                }
```

The advantage to this approach over a simple NavigationLink is that our button can do any amount of other work before triggering the programmatic navigation.
**e.g.** maybe you want to save some data or authenticate the user etc..

**Updated**

Here is another method without deprecated message

```
@State private var isShowingDetailsView : Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
           VStack {
              Button {
                  //Code here before changing the bool value
                  isShowingDetailsView = true
              } label: {
                  Text(“Tap to show details”)
              }
          }
           .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isShowingDetailsView) {
              DetailsView()
          }
       }
   }
}
```

But this method can be used only in iOS 16 or above

Comment: it worked but it adding "Tap to show detail" text on horizontal list by using 1st approach, by 2nd approach it replaceable with "" in Button title and worked fine with ** was deprecated in iOS 16.0**, is any other method without **deprecated**  message?

Comment: Hi @DeepakSingh Answer is updated with new method without deprecated message.